# Android, Apple sign in

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to add Apple sign-in functionality to my Android App.
I follow the pop-up approach.
I'm failing to get it to work.

```
class AppleLoginWebViewActivity : BaseActivity(), AppleLoginContract.View {

   private val TAG = AppleLoginWebViewActivity::class.java.simpleName

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_apple_login)

       prepareWebView()
   }

   private fun prepareWebView() {

       if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
           WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
       }

       webView.addJavascriptInterface(
           AppleLoginJavaScriptInterface(),
           "AndroidInterface"
       )

       val webSettings: WebSettings = webView.settings
       webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
       webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
       webView.webChromeClient = MyWebChromeClient()
       webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
       webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
       webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
   }

   private inner class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

       override fun onPageFinished(
           view: WebView,
           url: String
       ) { //Calling a javascript function in html page
           Logger.info(TAG, "page started: $url")
           // view.loadUrl("javascript:alert(clickAppleSignInButton())")
           view.loadUrl("javascript:AndroidInterface.showHTML" +
               "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
       }

       override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
           view: WebView?,
           request: WebResourceRequest?
       ): Boolean {
           return false
       }
   }

   private class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient() {
       override fun onJsAlert(
           view: WebView,
           url: String,
           message: String,
           result: JsResult
       ): Boolean {
           result.confirm()
           return true
       }
   }

   override fun loadUrl(appleLoginLocalUrl: String) {
       webView.loadUrl(appleLoginLocalUrl)
   }
}
```

and here is the html file that I load

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Apple Sign in</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"></script>
<div id="appleid-signin" data-color="black" data-border="true" data-type="sign in"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

     const options = {
       clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
       scope: 'email name',
       redirectURI: 'MY_REDIRECT_URL',
       state: '',
       usePopup : true
     };
     AppleID.auth.init(options);
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   function clickAppleSignInButton() {
     document.getElementById("appleid-signin").click();
   }
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   //Listen for authorization success
   document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnSuccess', successFunction);
   //Listen for authorization failures
   document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnFailure', failureFunction);

   function successFunction(data) {
     //handle successful response
     console.log("success")
     AndroidInterface.onLoginSuccess(data);
   }

   function failureFunction(error) {
     //handle error
     console.log("failure")
     AndroidInterface.onLoginFailed(error);
   }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

SO, in the last step, when I inspect the web view, I can see the authentication data being posted (POST request) to another url inside the web view. But the event listener with `AppleIDSignInOnSuccess` is never called. there is an error that says `"Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('MY_REDIRECT_URL') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://appleid.apple.com').", source:  (0)`.

So, I have a couple of questions:

1. How to fix this error?
2. Why the event listener is not getting called?
3. Is there a way that I can intercept and parse the POST response from the web view directly?

Comment: I've implemented apple sign in using rest api. If you have a backend you can give it a try.

Comment: @AccessDenied how do you send the POST response back to the mobile app?

Comment: @Mirko, you have a webview and check to what page it's navigated, when redirect uri is reached, it's over.

Comment: @AccessDenied when I call the Apple Sign In from the webview, the browser opens and I get an error. I set `usePopup: true` but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     const options = {
       clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
       scope: 'email name',
       redirectURI: 'MY_REDIRECT_URL',
       state: '',
       usePopup : true
     };
     AppleID.auth.init(options);
     AppleID.auth.signIn(); //<-- there :)
 </script>
```

- Apple wants that redirect url to be full really url, like: 
  `https://some.domain.tld/path/to/redirect` which supports POST
- Also not all browsers support usePopup, for example iOS 10.3 block this for me :)

Comment: But what `MY_REDIRECT_URL` should we specify to get back to the Android app? We cannot use localhost, so the POST request will go to a server, then get lost?

Comment: usePopup does not work on ios 12 and Android 10, so how are we supposed to log users in?

Comment: @Mirko Yes you should set MY_REDIRECT_URL as HTTPS endpoint with server certificate (not self signed of course), that handle apple messages about Authorization. Yes, as I mentioned before, no all browser support pop-up for this page.. and I don't know how to fix that (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the page hasn't finished loading yet. Try changing

```
document.getElementById("appleid-signin").click();
```

to

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("appleid-signin").click();
});
```

You can set up remote debugging with Chrome which will allow you to use Chrome Dev Tools to debug your webview with your device connected. Docs here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging